# How do I get an html node with a specific data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

In javaScript, how is the best way to get a specific html node where I know the attribute name and attribute value, and many html nodes can have the same attribute name? The attribute name is a data attribute.

Here is some example html:

```
<div class="misc1" data-test="value1" data-test="value2"></div>
<div class="misc2" data-test="value3" data-test="value4"></div>
```

If I want to get the html node with `data-test="value3"`, do I need to do something along the lines of:

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-test]");
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    for(x = 0; x < elements[i].attributes.length; x++) {
        //Do an attribute value check??
    }
  }
```

Can I please have some help with the code and I would not like to use jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Your [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) can be made more specific like so:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="value3"]');
```

There are multiple other variations of the attribute selector as well:

> - `[attr]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.
> - `[attr=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".
> - `[attr~=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is
>     exactly "value".
> - `[attr|=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr. Its value can be exactly “value” or can begin with “value”
>     immediately followed by “-” (U+002D). It can be used for language
>     subcode matches.
> - `[attr^=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".
> - `[attr$=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is suffixed by "value".
> - `[attr*=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as
>     substring.
> - `[attr operator value i]` Adding an i before the closing bracket causes the value to be compared case-insensitively (for characters
>     within the ASCII range).

Comment: this is correct answer, I always feel it necessary though to see if OP is intentionally trying to avoid jQuery , or just don't realize how much easier stuff like this is

Comment: @ScottSelby Sorry about that :-)